# How to get the number of tags having certain property using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML like:

```
<div id="abc">
 <li></li>
 <li style="display: none;">lorem ipsum</li>
 <li></li>
 <li style="display: none;">lorem ipsum</li>
 <li></li>
</div>
```

I want to get the count of "li" tags under the "abc id" having style="display: none;".
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `.not(":visible")` method for that.

```
$("#abc li").not(":visible").length
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/222/)

Comment: Thankx @Anoop. Got it exactly I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :hidden to get all display:none elements. do:

```
 $( "#abc" ).find( ":hidden" ).length
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var getInvisibleLi = function(id) {
  return $('#' + id).find('li').not(':visible').length;
}

alert(getInvisibleLi('abc'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
 <li>test</li>
 <li style="display: none;">lorem ipsum</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li style="display: none;">lorem ipsum</li>
 <li>test</li>
</div>
```